# Exporting raster map for printing

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3

I'm trying to export my colored raster map. Colors are very important for me. But I couldn't export it according to my colors. When I tried different methods it gives an error:

> output file format with specified pixel type or number of bands or colormap is not supported

or whole map is black. I mean even out of study area boundaries.
[image]
Any solution to this?

I am using ArcGIS 10.3.1 for Desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're exporting for the purposes of printing, you're using the wrong Export command. The one you're using (which is launched by right-clicking the layer and clicking "Export") is for exporting your raster data to another raster format. The export command you want to use is under the File menu, `File > Export Map`. You can export to PDF, TIFF, PNG, EPS, or a few other formats, whatever's best for your print setup.

Comment: I knew I'm doing it with stupid mistake! :-D Many thanks!